# Перезапись модели в виде - почему странно работают хелперы

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Всем привет. Помогите понять почему вьюшка ничего не показывает. 
Есть след. код.
Модель

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcApplication3.Models
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Вьюха

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.Class1

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @{
            ViewData.Model = new MvcApplication3.Models.Class1() { ID = 16, Name = "Denis", Message = "Hello world" };
         }
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ID)<br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)<br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Message)<br />

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Контроллер

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication3.Models;
namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Собственно вопрос в том, почему если код

```
ViewData.Model = new MvcApplication3.Models.Class1() { ID = 16, Name = "Denis", Message = "Hello world" };
```

во вьюхе убрать и вставить его в контролл в качестве параметра таким образом

```
View(new MvcApplication3.Models.Class1() { ID = 16, Name = "Denis", Message = "Hello world" })
```

в методе Index тогда все работает отлично. Ведь по сути присваивание ViewData.Model любого значения это и есть передача модели, где бы она не происходила, хоть во вью, хоть в контроле. Но здесь почему-то очень важно чтобы именно передавалась модель через метод View. Почему так ?? И второе, если я использую вместо

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ID)<br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)<br />
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Message)<br />
```

Строку

```
@Html.DisplayForModel
```

тогда все работает нормально. Опять же почему так происходит ? Ведь по идее если в первом случае оно не работает , то и во втором не должно ? Спасибо. Прилагаю в архиве проект этот.
К сожалению не понял как сюда залить файл поэтому кину ссылку на сторонний ресурс

[Код проекта](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2Byc7itmqWNN/MvcApplication3.zip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что существует два класса `HtmlHelper` - базовый универсальный и его обобщенный наследник. И если базовый использует то же самое свойство `ViewData`, что и страница - то наследник мало того, что это свойство переопределяет - так еще и клонирует его в своем конструкторе. Поэтому присваивание `ViewData.Model = ...` отражается только на поведении хелперов из базового класса, но не из класса-наследника.

Метод `DisplayFor` обобщенный - а значит, относится к хелперу-наследнику `HtmlHelper<TModel>`. Потому и не работает (там закешировался null в качестве модели). Метод же `DisplayForModel` работает с базовым классом, который обладает актуальной информацией о модели.

В качестве костыля, могу предложить делать вот так:

```
ViewData.Model = Html.ViewData.Model = new MvcApplication3.Models.Class1() { ID = 16, Name = "Denis", Message = "Hello world" };
```

Но, вообще говоря, `HtmlHelper<TModel>` - не единственное потенциальное проблемное место. Поэтому лучше всего вспомнить о том, что модель в понимании MVC - это объект, передаваемый от контроллера к виду - и воздержаться от экспериментов по его замене в уже сформированном виде.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень просветили и помогли.